# OpenJDK does not work with javafx

Tags: java, linux, netbeans, javafx

I have just installed Fedora 21 on my laptop and installed OpenJDK8(JDK), Netbeans and SceneBuilder.When I create a new JavaFX project the following message appears:
[image]
 I can only fix it if I add the Oracle Java 8 under Manage Platform. How can I get these done with OpenJDK only?

Comment: Related question: [JavaFX and OpenJDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547362/javafx-and-openjdk)

Answer (score 0):

Where from did you install openjdk? If used the one coming from fedora it does NOT have javafx with it which sort of is ok from the fedora point of view because JavaFX - although it is an openjdk project - is not jsred and so there's not must to include it.

IIRC the problem for Fedora and other linux distros was/is that they did not get some of the native parts built from Source which is something they require for all stuff they ship!

Comment: I simply installed with yum so yes, the one that comes from fedora. So from where should I install openjdk?

Comment: Frankly i don't know because i'm using oracle jdk and/or ea builds who i get from https://jdk8.java.net/download.html

Comment: @tomsontom - when you say OpenJDK, it means the OpenJDK project, not Oracle, nor any other JDK implementation. OpenJFX is still not stable, and that is I believe one of the main reasons openjdk distributions do not ship it. For JavaFX one definitely needs Oracle's JDK (at least to get the JavaFX jar).