# R version 3.1.2, ubuntu 3.13.0-44-generic, how to install rjava?

Tags: java, r, ubuntu, rjava

It keeps saying this:

configure: error: 
**Java Development Kit (JDK) is missing or not registered in R**

Make sure R is configured with full Java support (including JDK). Run
R CMD javareconf as root to add Java support to R.

If you don't have root privileges, run
R CMD javareconf -e
to set all Java-related variables and then install rJava.

I have follow the link([How to install JDK on Ubuntu (Linux)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14788345/how-to-install-jdk-on-ubuntu-linux)) to install JDK and setup the path,but when I try to install rJava , it says this again and again.

Anyone can help me figure out?

Thank you very much and have a nice day!

Comment: What "keeps saying this" exactly? Which command?

Comment: configure: error: Java Development Kit (JDK) is missing or not registered in R

Make sure R is configured with full Java support (including JDK). Run R CMD javareconf as root to add Java support to R.

If you don't have root privileges, run R CMD javareconf -e to set all Java-related variables and then install rJava.

Comment: Every time I install it shows the configure error showed above

Comment: What is the exact output of `R CMD javareconf`?

Comment: Problem Solved! Here is the solution link:http://allanino.me/blog/programming/installing-some-r-packages/