# Error of java path on loading rJava package

Tags: java, r, unix, rjava

I am trying to load 'rJava' package in my Unix machine.
Before loading I have set the path using

```
Sys.setenv("JAVA_HOME= myfilepath")
```

in my R script.

Despite this I am getting the following error (Below is the part of the error):

```
checking Java support in R... present:
interpreter : '/usr/lib/jvm/jre/bin/java'
archiver    : '/usr/lib/jvm/jre/../bin/jar'
compiler    : '/usr/lib/jvm/jre/../bin/javac'
header prep.: '/usr/lib/jvm/jre/../bin/javah'
cpp flags   : '-I/usr/lib/jvm/java/include I/usr/lib/jvm/java/include/linux'
java libs   : '-L/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/server -ljvm'
checking whether Java run-time works... ./configure: line 3729: /usr/lib/jvm/jre/bin/java: No such file or directory
no configure: error: Java interpreter '/usr/lib/jvm/jre/bin/java' does not work
```

As you can see the error shows that **/usr/lib/jvm/jre/bin/java: No such file or directory**.
But I have not set this as *myfilepath*. 
How do I prevent the installer from looking at this path?

Kindly help.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311940/r-rjava-package-install-failing) maybe. There are some good tips there.

Comment: I had check that post before posting the question.
I tried everything there. Does not seem to work for me.

Comment: Did you tried `sudo R CMD javareconf` I had the same problem. rJava trying to check the directories which is not at all there in my system. But after running the above config command, it worked for me.

Comment: thanks Manoj sudo R CMD javareconf worked for me.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

```
sudo R CMD javareconf
```

This works perfectly. Keeping this here if someone reads this in future.

Comment: This didn't have any effect for me (Mint 18).

Comment: @Deleet Worked for me (Ubuntu Server 16.04) , after I installed openjdk-7-jdk

Comment: Worked for me, ubuntu 16.04.2!

Comment: For this to work you need to have java installed first. See here for instructions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14788345/how-to-install-jdk-on-ubuntu-linux

Comment: After `sudo R CMD javareconf`, run `sudo rstudio-server restart`.

Comment: Also note that as of version 0.9-12(2020-03-23) rJava has an --enable-dynload option to enable dynamic loading of the JVM. The changelog also shows the order rJava uses to search for the JVM which might be useful. https://github.com/s-u/rJava/blob/master/NEWS

Answer (score 3):

I have a VM of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on VirtualBox, and the real path of installation of my java-jdk is the following :

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
```

This command worked  very fine for my situation. 
I had this type of error from installation o rJava package on RStudio:

```
*./configure: line 3736: /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/jre/bin/java: No such file or directory*
```

First I' have modified the profile in this way : 
sudo gedit /etc/profile  and then added this  instructions at the eof:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME
export PATH
```

After this, from terminal session I've typed the command:

```
sudo R CMD javareconf
```

and the package rJava was successfully installed.

Note: You might also have to set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` [environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428910/how-to-set-the-environmental-variable-ld-library-path-in-linux), before running `sudo R CMD javareconf`.

Answer (score 0):

Faced same problem in Ubuntu 14.04. This installation guide was helpful for me after going through a straightforward installation. 
http://www.korecky.org/?p=1254 (Installation of R) and 
[http://www.korecky.org/?p=847] (Installation of Java)

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.