# Installing XLConnect package

Tags: r, rjava, xlconnect

I was wanting to install XLConnect package so that i could save my databses created from RSQLite in different formats. But when i do

```
install.packages("XLConnect")
```

it seems to give error

```
checking whether Java run-time works... ./configure: line 3747: /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/java: No such file or directory
no
configure: error: Java interpreter '/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/java' does not work
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rJava’
* removing ‘/home/mrshekar/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/rJava’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rJava’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘rJava’ is not available for package ‘XLConnectJars’
* removing ‘/home/mrshekar/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/XLConnectJars’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘XLConnectJars’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘XLConnectJars’, ‘rJava’ are not available for package ‘XLConnect’
* removing ‘/home/mrshekar/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/XLConnect’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘XLConnect’ had non-zero exit status
```

Now i read on [R: rJava package install failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311940/r-rjava-package-install-failing) about the

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

but still the problem seeems to persist. Also if you look at the solution on [Error of java path on loading rJava package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30572258/error-of-java-path-on-loading-rjava-package)

```
sudo R CMD javareconf
```

It gives the error

```
*** JAVA_HOME is not a valid path, ignoring

*** Cannot find any Java interpreter
*** Please make sure 'java' is on your PATH or set JAVA_HOME correspondingly
```

Also for the install JDK answer

```
apt-get install r-cran-rjava
```

I get the permission denied error even if i do it on vm-virtual box it gives me permission denied for the ubuntu 18.04 version i have installed and made myself the admin.

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

What should i do? Please help.

Comment: The best practice with rJava seems to be avoid using this annoying package wherever possible. switching R versions to or from 32/64 bit in global options sometimes works. Alternatively could you use a non Java connection package like `odbc` instead?

Comment: can i save the databases i create using the dbConnect as .csv or other formats using odbc? @Shinobi_Atobe

Comment: yes, you can use tools from the `DBI` package: i.e  `df <- dbGetQuery(connection, "select * from xxxx")`