# Error When Building a Java Project on IntelliJ IDEA - java: No such file or directory

Tags: java, linux, intellij-idea, build, default

**My Environment:**

Java: `1.8.0_392`, Apache Maven: `3.6.3` on an Ubuntu Linux `x86_64`.
When I create a new project in IntelliJ IDEA, I got the following error:

```
Executing pre-compile tasks…
Abnormal build process termination:
nice -n 10 /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/java -Xmx700m 
-Djava.awt.headless=true -Djna.boot.library.
    path=/snap/intellij-idea-community/475/lib/ jna/amd64 
-Djna.nosys=true -Djna.noclasspath=true -Dpreload.project.
    path=/home/mi/IdeaProjects/demo1 
-Dpreload.config.path=/home/mi/.config/JetBrains/IdeaIC2023.3 /options 
-Dexternal.project.config=/home/mi/.cache/JetBrains/IdeaIC2023.3/projects/demo1.427dd562/external_build_system -Dcompile.parallel=false -Drebuild.on.dependency.change=true -Didea.IntToIntBtree .page.size=32768 -Djdt.compiler.useSingleThread=true -Daether.connector.resumeDownloads=false -Dio.netty.initialSeedUniquifier=3917806107211059579 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.language=zh -Duser.country=CN -Didea.paths.selector=IdeaIC2023.3 -Didea.home.path=/snap/intellij-idea-community/475 -Didea.config.path=/home/mi/.config/JetBrains/IdeaIC2023.3 -Didea. plugins.path=/home/mi/.local/share/JetBrains/IdeaIC2023.3 -Djps.log.dir=/home/mi/.cache/JetBrains/IdeaIC2023.3/log/build-log -Djps.fallback. jdk.home=/snap/intellij-idea-community/475/jbr -Djps.fallback.jdk.version=17.0.9 -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/mi/.cache /JetBrains/IdeaIC2023.3/compile-server/demo1_d31a0138/_temp_ -Djps.backward.ref.index.builder=true -Djps.kotlin.home=/snap/intellij-idea-community/475/plugins/Kotlin/kotlinc - Dkotlin.incremental.compilation=true -Dkotlin.incremental.compilation.js=true -Dkotlin.daemon.enabled -Dkotlin.daemon.client.alive.path=\"/tmp/kotlin-idea-11008715337566427978-is-running\" -Dide.propagate.context=false -classpath /snap/intellij-idea-community/475/plugins/java/lib/jps-launcher.jar org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.Launcher /snap/intellij-idea-community/ 475/plugins/java/lib/jps-builders.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/475/plugins/java/lib/jps-builders-6.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/475/ plugins/java/lib/jps-javac-extension.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/475/lib/util-8.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/475/lib/util_rt.jar: /snap/intellij-idea-community/475/lib/platform-loader.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/475/lib/annotations.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/475/lib/protobuf .jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/475/lib/jps-model.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/475/plugins/java/lib/javac2.jar:/snap/intellij-idea- community/475/lib/forms_rt.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/475/lib/util.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/475/plugins/java/lib/aether-dependency-resolver. jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/475/plugins/java/lib/maven-resolver-connector-basic.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/475/plugins/java/lib/maven-resolver- transport-file.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/475/plugins/java/lib/maven-resolver-transport-http.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/475/lib/idea_rt.jar: /snap/intellij-idea-community/475/plugins/Kotlin/lib/jps/kotlin-jps-plugin.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/475/lib/util-8.jar:/snap/intellij -idea-community/475/plugins/eclipse/lib/eclipse-jps.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/475/plugins/eclipse/lib/eclipse-common.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community /475/plugins/platform-langInjection/lib/java-langInjection-jps.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/475/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-jps.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community /475/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-constants-rt.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/475/plugins/javaFX/lib/javaFX-jps.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/475 /plugins/javaFX/lib/javaFX-common.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/475/plugins/uiDesigner/lib/jps/java-guiForms-jps.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/475 /plugins/maven/lib/maven-jps.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/475/plugins/space/lib/space-java-jps.jar:/snap/intellij-idea-community/475/plugins /gradle-java/lib/gradle-jps.jar org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain 127.0.0.1 36503 ad833636-3746-4830-9e1e-04530999cf78 /home/mi/.cache/JetBrains/IdeaIC2023.3/compile- server

nice: "/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/java": No such file or directory
```

Has anyone encountered a similar situation?
Thank you so much if you can give the solution, I am a new guy of software learner.

1. The first time when running the java main class of a new project, this error occurs.
   However, if I selected the options *"Do not build before run"*，I could run the Java class successfully.
   So, I infer that this problem is related to building the project.
2. Before installing OpenJDK 8, I accidentally executed this instruction:

```bash
$ sudo apt install defatult-jdk
```

Then I installed OpenJDK 8 via this command:

```bash
$ sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk
```

I suspect the error's root cause is:

```
"/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/java": No such file or directory
```

This may be related to the installation of `defatult-jdk`, but I am not familiar with Linux and don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: Please check this:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/30572258/16811915

Comment: The problem has fixed, after I select the correct java JDK path in run configuration -> build and run settings

Answer (score 0):

If javajdk installed in your linux system then , you need to configure it in intellije IDEA .
Went to **run configuration** on  and select the current download version of jdk .