# JDK 8 is NOT installed - ERROR 404: Not Found

Tags: java, ubuntu, java-8

Since yesterday, I've been trying to install the JDK8 on my Ubuntu machine, but it has been failing constantly.

I've been trying to run the commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java -y
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
```

But I can't continue because when running the command `sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer` all I get is:

```
...
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|23.215.130.99|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2017-10-18 11:07:34 ERROR 404: Not Found.

download failed
Oracle JDK 8 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
...
```

My Setup is a 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

After a lot of googling around I found a answer on [the Ubuntu forum](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2374686).

Basically, the problem seems to be that there is a new version of java and the installer wasn't updated to reference it.

If your machine is a **Linux x64** with an **AMD64** processor, you need the latest Java8 version, and you previously installed version `8u212`, this can be easily fixed by running these commands (Credit for the original version goes to [g1zmo2](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2374686&p=13699384#post13699384)):

```
cd /var/lib/dpkg/info
sudo sed -i 's|JAVA_VERSION=8u212|JAVA_VERSION=8u221|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sudo sed -i 's|PARTNER_URL=https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/jdk/8u212-b10/59066701cf1a433da9770636fbc4c9aa/|PARTNER_URL=https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/jdk/8u221-b11/230deb18db3e4014bb8e3e8324f81b43/|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sudo sed -i 's|SHA256SUM_TGZ=.*|SHA256SUM_TGZ="15ad4f7260d2416ac1558341d9d0a0ec5b83904e4ac4a22c8a3242e4e217649b"|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sudo sed -i 's|J_DIR=jdk1.8.0_212|J_DIR=jdk1.8.0_2221|' oracle-java8-installer.*
```

And then running the JDK 8 installer commands like you normally would =):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
```

---

If your machine is **not** a **Linux x64 AMD64**, your previous version wasn't `8u212` or **you are looking for Java 9**, well, you are in luck. Today is the day you'll learn to fix your java installer for your own needs.

For the purposes of this tutorial, we'll assume you want Java 8u181 and you had previously installed Java 8u171 (because that's what I have).

First, I need you to go to Java's JDK Downloads page (For Java8, [go here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/index.html), click the "Downloads" [tab](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html), and then the "Java SE 8u181" [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)).

Now, look up the JDK version you need based on your machine. In my case, my machine is running on Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit, so I need "Linux x64".

[image: JDK versions]

Copy the link that takes you to the download you need. Don't forget to accept the license agreement. In my case (Linux x64), I need: `http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u181-b13/96a7b8442fe848ef90c96a2fad6ed6d1/jdk-8u181-linux-x64.tar.gz`.

For the purposes of this tutorial, we only need the link's path: `http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u181-b13/96a7b8442fe848ef90c96a2fad6ed6d1/`. Keep it safe; we'll need it later.

Now look up the checksum link in the page and [click it](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/s/digest/8u181checksum.html).

[image: Checksum link]

This should take you to a plain html table page. Just look for the `sha256` that fits your machine.

[image: Linux x64 SHA]

Again, my machine is a "Linux x64" so I need `1845567095bfbfebd42ed0d09397939796d05456290fb20a83c476ba09f991d3`, like in the picture. Copy the value, and keep it safe; we'll need it later too.

Now, open a terminal on your machine and enter the folder where the java installer file are:

```
cd /var/lib/dpkg/info
```

Great, now execute this:

```
sudo grep --color -P "JAVA_VERSION=[a-z0-9]+" oracle-java8-installer.config
```

The output should look something like this:

[image: Installer's java version]

This tells us what is the java version that the installer is configured to install. So to change those values easily we would run something like this:

```
sudo sed -i 's|JAVA_VERSION=<INSTALLER CURRENT JAVA VERSION HERE>|JAVA_VERSION=<NEW VERSION HERE>|' oracle-java8-installer.*
```

For our case, we are upgrading from `8u171` to `8u181`, so we would execute:

```
sudo sed -i 's|JAVA_VERSION=8u171|JAVA_VERSION=8u181|' oracle-java8-installer.*
```

Ok, now we need to update the download url.

```
sudo grep --color -P "PARTNER_URL=[^ ]+" oracle-java8-installer.config
```

[image: Installer's partner url]

To update it, we should execute a command like this:

```
sudo sed -i 's|PARTNER_URL=<INSTALLER CURRENT JAVA URL HERE>|PARTNER_URL=<NEW URL HERE>|' oracle-java8-installer.*
```

Remember that URL I told you to save at the start? Well, we'll need it now. Place it as your new url, like this:

```
sudo sed -i 's|PARTNER_URL=http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u171-b11/512cd62ec5174c3487ac17c61aaa89e8/|PARTNER_URL=http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u181-b13/96a7b8442fe848ef90c96a2fad6ed6d1/|' oracle-java8-installer.*
```

After that, we need to update the checksum. So please execute this command:

```
sudo grep --color -P '[^#]SHA256SUM_TGZ="[^"]+"' oracle-java8-installer.config
```

This prints out a couple different SHA256:

[image: Installer's SHA256s]

Notice that they are all different. We'll get back at that in a second. So, to update the SHA256, we would need to execute this command:

```
sudo sed -i 's|SHA256SUM_TGZ="<INSTALLER CURRENT JAVA HASH HERE>"|SHA256SUM_TGZ="<NEW JAVA HASH>"|' oracle-java8-installer.*
```

But how do we know which of the current Java hashes to replace? Well, we need to find out our processor's architecture:

```
dpkg --print-architecture
```

In my case, this will output `amd64`. This means I should grab the second link. How do I know this? Well, I read the source code (`sudo gedit oracle-java8-installer.config`), so trust me on this:

- If your architecture is `i386`, `i586` or `i686`, grab the first one.
- If `amd64`, grab the second one.
- If `armv7l` or `armv6l`, grab the third one.
- If `armv8l`, `arm64` or `aarch64`, grab the fourth one.
- If none of the above, you are out of luck...

So, as mine is `amd64`, using the new hash we obtained from Java's website, I would execute:

```
sudo sed -i 's|SHA256SUM_TGZ="b6dd2837efaaec4109b36cfbb94a774db100029f98b0d78be68c27bec0275982"|SHA256SUM_TGZ="1845567095bfbfebd42ed0d09397939796d05456290fb20a83c476ba09f991d3"|' oracle-java8-installer.*
```

Finally, we need to modify the installers JDK directory name, so execute this to find the current one:

```
sudo grep --color -P "J_DIR=[^ ]+" oracle-java8-installer.config
```

In my case this printed:

[image: Installer's JDK folder name]

So we would execute something like this:

```
sudo sed -i 's|J_DIR=<INSTALLER CURRENT JDK VERSION HERE>|J_DIR=<NEW JDK VERSION>|' oracle-java8-installer.*
```

Being my current version `jdk1.8.0_171`, I execute:

```
sudo sed -i 's|J_DIR=jdk1.8.0_171|J_DIR=jdk1.8.0_181|' oracle-java8-installer.*
```

And... that's it. We are ready to call the java installer, yay.  (phew... this took longer to type that I thought at first).

Comment: Fix for 8u151-1~webupd8~0:

Comment: It looks like it is outdated again with java 8u161 (404 not found), anybody has an updated fix?

Comment: I just tested @Kenny Hung's version, about 1 hour ago, and it worked. The answer was updated accordingly (it was copied it wrong, sorry about that).

Comment: this seems to install 171, but not 172 : sudo sed -i 's|JAVA_VERSION=8u161|JAVA_VERSION=8u172|' oracle-java8-installer.*

Comment: You are right @Pavlo, kinda odd =\
Removing it to not leave room for confusion

Comment: Thanks a lot. This answer helped. But it sucks that people have to keep adding answers to this post every time a new version of JDK is released. Do you think you could edit your answer to be more generic?

For example, at each `sed` step, I first used `grep` to see the current value and got the new value based on the JDK version that is currently the latest. I then modified your strings accordingly with the new 'before' and 'after's (with the exception of the SHA line. I just commented out the SHA256 check in the script because I wasn't bothered. Probably not the best of ideas...)

Comment: Yup, sucks a lot =\ I could work on a guide to do it manually =), but sometimes one is just a Linux nooby (I was one at some point not so long ago), and a copy-paste command *really* helps a lot. I'll take the best of both worlds, thanks for the suggestion. =)

Comment: @GeorgeV.M. it is done ^_^ Let me know if you have any other suggestion

Comment: The "manual" fix also works for Raspberry Pi/Raspbian Stretch, but you have to use the "jdk-8u201-linux-arm32-vfp-hflt.tar.gz" version of SHA from https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/s/digest/8u201checksum.html (for the 8u201 version).

Comment: I've failed to get this to work for both 8u211 and 8u212. I noticed the download url is now using https and otn instead of otn-pub. Trying that just gives unauthorized instead of not found. I don't suppose the recent license change is a factor?

Answer (score 10):

Thanks for cavpollo's answer for JDK 8u141.

I'll give fix for **JDK 8u151-1~webupd8~0** (Use JDK 8i162 instead):

```
cd /var/lib/dpkg/info
sudo sed -i 's|JAVA_VERSION=8u151|JAVA_VERSION=8u162|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sudo sed -i 's|PARTNER_URL=http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u151-b12/e758a0de34e24606bca991d704f6dcbf/|PARTNER_URL=http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u162-b12/0da788060d494f5095bf8624735fa2f1/|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sudo sed -i 's|SHA256SUM_TGZ="c78200ce409367b296ec39be4427f020e2c585470c4eed01021feada576f027f"|SHA256SUM_TGZ="68ec82d47fd9c2b8eb84225b6db398a72008285fafc98631b1ff8d2229680257"|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sudo sed -i 's|J_DIR=jdk1.8.0_151|J_DIR=jdk1.8.0_162|' oracle-java8-installer.*
```

Answer (score 9):

Hit this today with Oracle moving from 8u181 to 8u191. Followed @cavpollo's steps and got it working for my stuff here is the fix for 181 to 191 in case anyone needs it:

```
cd /var/lib/dpkg/info
sudo sed -i 's|JAVA_VERSION=8u181|JAVA_VERSION=8u191|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sudo sed -i 's|PARTNER_URL=http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u181-b13/96a7b8442fe848ef90c96a2fad6ed6d1/|PARTNER_URL=http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u191-b12/2787e4a523244c269598db4e85c51e0c/|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sudo sed -i 's|SHA256SUM_TGZ="1845567095bfbfebd42ed0d09397939796d05456290fb20a83c476ba09f991d3"|SHA256SUM_TGZ="53c29507e2405a7ffdbba627e6d64856089b094867479edc5ede4105c1da0d65"|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sudo sed -i 's|J_DIR=jdk1.8.0_181|J_DIR=jdk1.8.0_191|' oracle-java8-installer.*
```

Comment: Thanks for this updated version. Glad to know the tutorial worked for you =)

Comment: Yup worked great, thanks so much for making such a well documented tutorial!

Answer (score 7):

Since a few days ago this workaround is obsolete due to the new java release. Instead, use this replacement:

```
sed -i 's|JAVA_VERSION=8u151|JAVA_VERSION=8u162|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sed -i 's|PARTNER_URL=http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u151-b12/e758a0de34e24606bca991d704f6dcbf/|PARTNER_URL=http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u162-b12/0da788060d494f5095bf8624735fa2f1/|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sed -i 's|SHA256SUM_TGZ="c78200ce409367b296ec39be4427f020e2c585470c4eed01021feada576f027f"|SHA256SUM_TGZ="68ec82d47fd9c2b8eb84225b6db398a72008285fafc98631b1ff8d2229680257"|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sed -i 's|J_DIR=jdk1.8.0_151|J_DIR=jdk1.8.0_162|' oracle-java8-installer.*
```

Comment: Thanks. Here I am staying at work late on a Friday because my ansible web server deployment playbook can't install java on hosts any more, because, presumably, Oracle won't let vendors redistribute a binary they don't even charge money for. 

As if there weren't enough reasons to switch to an open source alternative.

Answer (score 6):

For the update changes made on **16th April 2019**, for **Linux x64** on **AMD64** going from `8u201` to `8u211` add the following:

```
cd /var/lib/dpkg/info
sudo sed -i 's|JAVA_VERSION=8u201|JAVA_VERSION=8u211|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sudo sed -i 's|PARTNER_URL=http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u201-b09/42970487e3af4f5aa5bca3f542482c60/|PARTNER_URL=https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/jdk/8u211-b12/478a62b7d4e34b78b671c754eaaf38ab/|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sudo sed -i 's|SHA256SUM_TGZ="cb700cc0ac3ddc728a567c350881ce7e25118eaf7ca97ca9705d4580c506e370"|SHA256SUM_TGZ="c0b7e45330c3f79750c89de6ee0d949ed4af946849592154874d22abc9c4668d"|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sudo sed -i 's|J_DIR=jdk1.8.0_201|J_DIR=jdk1.8.0_211|' oracle-java8-installer.*
```

In my case I don't need to use `sudo` but for consistency with other responses here I have left it in.

Thanks to @cavpollo

Comment: Came to this set of commands myself. Tried yours, but in both cases I'm getting a HTTP '401 Authorization Required'.

Comment: And here I am, 17th April 2019. Wtf is wrong with these unreliable installers. This is so reckless from their part. Half of the planet depends on this. Lesson learn, backup everything.

Comment: suspect the 401 is because 8u211 is the first version that is paid only. The previous 8u201 was the last freely available version. It looks to me as though the tarball referenced by the 8u201 version has been removed from Oracle's servers?

Comment: I am trying to add this to my dockerfile but I keep getting this error `sed: can't read oracle-java8-installer.*: No such file or directory`. Any idea about this?

Comment: I ended up stashing the 8u202 .tar.gz in S3 and changing the sed command to point to its location in a public S3 bucket, worked fine that way.

Answer (score 5):

The following was my workaround for Ubuntu Mate 16.04 x64:

```
wget --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u152-b16/aa0333dd3019491ca4f6ddbe78cdb6d0/jdk-8u152-linux-x64.tar.gz

mkdir /opt/jdk

sudo tar -zxf jdk-8u152-linux-x64.tar.gz -C /opt/jdk

update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_152/bin/java 100

update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_152/bin/javac 100
```

Credit to [digital ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-manually-install-oracle-java-on-a-debian-or-ubuntu-vps) for the header adjustment.

Answer (score 4):

Here it is for Java 8u181 as 8u171 is no longer working:

```
cd /var/lib/dpkg/info
sed -i 's|JAVA_VERSION=8u171|JAVA_VERSION=8u181|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sed -i 's|J_DIR=jdk1.8.0_171|J_DIR=jdk1.8.0_181|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sed -i 's|PARTNER_URL=http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u171-b11/512cd62ec5174c3487ac17c61aaa89e8/|PARTNER_URL=http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u181-b13/96a7b8442fe848ef90c96a2fad6ed6d1/|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sed -i 's|SHA256SUM_TGZ="b6dd2837efaaec4109b36cfbb94a774db100029f98b0d78be68c27bec0275982"|SHA256SUM_TGZ="1845567095bfbfebd42ed0d09397939796d05456290fb20a83c476ba09f991d3"|' oracle-java8-installer.*
```

Comment: Thanks for the updated version, I've updated the original answer to include it =)

Answer (score 3):

And a newer version:

```
cd /var/lib/dpkg/info
sudo sed -i 's|JAVA_VERSION=8u161|JAVA_VERSION=8u171|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sudo sed -i 's|PARTNER_URL=http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u161-b12/2f38c3b165be4555a1fa6e98c45e0808/|PARTNER_URL=http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u171-b11/512cd62ec5174c3487ac17c61aaa89e8/|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sudo sed -i 's|SHA256SUM_TGZ="6dbc56a0e3310b69e91bb64db63a485bd7b6a8083f08e48047276380a0e2021e"|SHA256SUM_TGZ="b6dd2837efaaec4109b36cfbb94a774db100029f98b0d78be68c27bec0275982"|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sudo sed -i 's|J_DIR=jdk1.8.0_161|J_DIR=jdk1.8.0_171|' oracle-java8-installer.*
```

Comment: Thanks for the updated version, I've updated the original answer to include it =)

Comment: That's fab. If this is going to be a common thing, we should probably document how to produce these hashes.

Comment: That's a very good idea. You could make your own question on SO and answer it. I would link to it from this question =)

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @cavpollo's answer, for those using Ansible, this task will get you there

```
- name: Patch Java installer
  shell: "{{ item }}"
  args:
    chdir: "/var/lib/dpkg/info"
  become: yes
  with_items:
    - sed -i 's|JAVA_VERSION=8u144|JAVA_VERSION=8u152|' oracle-java8-installer.*
    - sed -i 's|PARTNER_URL=http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u144-b01/090f390dda5b47b9b721c7dfaa008135/|PARTNER_URL=http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u152-b16/aa0333dd3019491ca4f6ddbe78cdb6d0/|' oracle-java8-installer.*
    - sed -i 's|SHA256SUM_TGZ="e8a341ce566f32c3d06f6d0f0eeea9a0f434f538d22af949ae58bc86f2eeaae4"|SHA256SUM_TGZ="218b3b340c3f6d05d940b817d0270dfe0cfd657a636bad074dcabe0c111961bf"|' oracle-java8-installer.*
    - sed -i 's|J_DIR=jdk1.8.0_144|J_DIR=jdk1.8.0_152|' oracle-java8-installer.*
```

Answer (score 2):

Let me share with you an update for JDK version 8u172

```
sudo sed -i 's|JAVA_VERSION=8u161|JAVA_VERSION=8u172|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sudo sed -i 's|PARTNER_URL=http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u161-b12/2f38c3b165be4555a1fa6e98c45e0808/|PARTNER_URL=http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u172-b11/a58eab1ec242421181065cdc37240b08/|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sudo sed -i 's|SHA256SUM_TGZ="6dbc56a0e3310b69e91bb64db63a485bd7b6a8083f08e48047276380a0e2021e"|SHA256SUM_TGZ="28a00b9400b6913563553e09e8024c286b506d8523334c93ddec6c9ec7e9d346"|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sudo sed -i 's|J_DIR=jdk1.8.0_161|J_DIR=jdk1.8.0_172|' oracle-java8-installer.*
```

Comment: Thanks for the updated version, I've updated the original answer to include it =)

Comment: According to @Pavlo this just installs version 8u171. Tested it myself on a 8u171 version, and nothing was updated.

Comment: Sorry cavpollo, that´s because “WebUpd8” team updated the version from 8u161 to 8u171 a few hours ago. This will no longer subtitute strings correctly. It was a patch for yesterdays error, Anyway I think you can use 8u171 SHA and URL posted by @kenny-hung intead of 8u161 versions. =)

Answer (score 2):

For the lastest version(jdk-8u211-linux-x64.tar.gz), you may get a HTTP '401 Authorization Required'.
My solution to this problem is as follows.

1. Go to the official website to download the jdk-8u211-linux-x64.tar.gz([here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)), you need to register an account before you download the file.
2. Install apache2 to build a Http server.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install apache2
   ```
3. Move the file you just download to the `/var/www/html` folder because the server default root directory is `/var/www/html`. Now you can download the file via url(Such as http://localhost/jdk-8u211-linux-x64.tar.gz).
4. Update the oracle-java8-installer.

   ```
   cd /var/lib/dpkg/info
   sudo sed -i 's|JAVA_VERSION=8u201|JAVA_VERSION=8u211|' oracle-java8-installer.*
   sudo sed -i 's|PARTNER_URL=http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u201-b09/42970487e3af4f5aa5bca3f542482c60/|PARTNER_URL=http://localhost/|' oracle-java8-installer.*
   sudo sed -i 's|SHA256SUM_TGZ="cb700cc0ac3ddc728a567c350881ce7e25118eaf7ca97ca9705d4580c506e370"|SHA256SUM_TGZ="c0b7e45330c3f79750c89de6ee0d949ed4af946849592154874d22abc9c4668d"|' oracle-java8-installer.*
   sudo sed -i 's|J_DIR=jdk1.8.0_201|J_DIR=jdk1.8.0_211|' oracle-java8-installer.*
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the link provided by oracle is not correct 
try this one
"http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/9.0.1+11/jdk-9.0.1_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz"

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u152-b16/aa0333dd3019491ca4f6ddbe78cdb6d0/jdk-8u152-linux-x64.tar.gz

Answer (score 1):

Above the .gz is missing from the URL for the download of java 8.
wget --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u152-b16/aa0333dd3019491ca4f6ddbe78cdb6d0/jdk-8u152-linux-x64.tar.gz