# How to install oracle-java8-installer on docker debian:jessie

Tags: docker, java-8, debian, debian-jessie

I am trying to install java 8 through oracle-java8-installer on a debian:jessie docker container. The following is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:jessie

ENV JAVA_VERSION 1.8.0

RUN echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-java.list
RUN echo "deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-java.list
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys EEA14886
RUN echo "debconf shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true" | /usr/bin/debconf-set-selections
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y --force-yes vim
RUN apt-get install -y --force-yes oracle-java8-installer
```

Yet this gives:

```
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|23.63.224.171|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2018-01-17 12:31:05 ERROR 404: Not Found.

download failed
Oracle JDK 8 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java8-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y --force-yes oracle-java8-installer' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

I have found many similar issues described online, but none of the proposed solutions worked for me. Any idea?

Comment: I have no relevant experience with docker, but I use Debian for some time and it looks not good to me that you are instlling a package from an ubuntu repository on Debian. When I need to install Oracle JDK I download it from the Oracle site and create a .deb file with java-package as described [here](https://wiki.debian.org/JavaPackage).

Answer (score 9):

Found the solution on https://hub.docker.com/r/anapsix/docker-oracle-java8/~/dockerfile/:

```
## JAVA INSTALLATION
RUN echo "oracle-java8-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true" | debconf-set-selections
RUN echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-java-trusty.list
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys EEA14886
RUN apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y --force-yes --no-install-recommends oracle-java8-installer && apt-get clean all
```

The "secret sauce" you were looking for is the first line:

```
RUN echo "oracle-java8-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true" | debconf-set-selections
```

Comment: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y --force-yes --no-install-recommends oracle-java8-installer && apt-get clean all' returned a non-zero code: 100

Answer (score 7):

Re to donhector's response and your question: you need to replace the strings in the installer file, **instead** of yours last command:

```
apt-get install -y --force-yes oracle-java8-installer
```

run these commands:

```
apt-get -y install oracle-java8-installer || true
cd /var/lib/dpkg/info

sed -i 's|JAVA_VERSION=8u151|JAVA_VERSION=8u162|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sed -i 's|PARTNER_URL=http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u151-b12/e758a0de34e24606bca991d704f6dcbf/|PARTNER_URL=http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u162-b12/0da788060d494f5095bf8624735fa2f1/|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sed -i 's|SHA256SUM_TGZ="c78200ce409367b296ec39be4427f020e2c585470c4eed01021feada576f027f"|SHA256SUM_TGZ="68ec82d47fd9c2b8eb84225b6db398a72008285fafc98631b1ff8d2229680257"|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sed -i 's|J_DIR=jdk1.8.0_151|J_DIR=jdk1.8.0_162|' oracle-java8-installer.*

apt-get install -f -y
apt-get install -y oracle-java8-set-default
```

I have them in a separate script and run it as

```
RUN /bin/sh /path/to/script.sh
```

or you can run them directly from your Dockerfile, that's up to you.

Comment: thanks Martin, you saved my time, I alsmost started to do it manually

Comment: what worked for me wasn't running the commands from the Dockerfile, BUT creating a script and using RUN /bin/sh /path/to/script.sh

Answer (score 5):

You are installing from the webupd8 PPA repo. If you notice, the Java 8 package in that repo points to Java 8 version `151`. That package pulls the binary for `151` from the Oracle servers (since Java Oracle licence does not allow anyone else hosting the binaries). Oracle released version `161` a couple days back and apparently moved or removed `151` from their servers. So basically the package in the webupd8 PPA repo is trying to download the `151` binary which no longer exists at the location that the webupd8 package expects it (hence the 404 you got). The webupd8 PPA repo maintainer will have to release a new package pointing to the new `161` binaries from Oracle. Docker or Debian don't play any role in the issue, it is just basically a broken link issue.

Until then you could apply a "workaround" like the one mentioned here: [JDK 8 is NOT installed - ERROR 404: Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46815897/jdk-8-is-not-installed-error-404-not-found)

Here's the list of Java packages in the webupd8 repo:

https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java/+packages

Comment: Linked "JDK 8 is NOT installed" answer was very helpful

Comment: Thanks for clear explanation @donhector. I get the idea of the workaround but I cannot understand how to implement it. Where should I add the following?

RUN apt-get --download-only -y --force-yes install oracle-java8-installer
RUN sed -i ... /var/cache/apt/archives/oracle-java8-installer*
...

Answer (score 2):

See [dpkg oracle Jdk error while installing cassandra in Ubuntu 16.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48301681/dpkg-oracle-jdk-error-while-installing-cassandra-in-ubuntu-16-04). This issue is occurring for everyone using install scripts of any kind.

Answer (score 1):

** Java 11:

```
RUN apt-get install wget java-common gnupg2 -y
RUN echo "oracle-java11-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-2 select true" | debconf-set-selections
RUN echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising/java/ubuntu bionic main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/linuxuprising-java.list
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 73C3DB2A
RUN apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends oracle-java11-installer && apt-get clean all
```