# dpkg oracle Jdk error while installing cassandra in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: java, cassandra, ubuntu-16.04, dpkg

I am trying to install Cassandra on aws ec2 free single node ubuntu instance. I am following this link https://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/DebianPackaging to install cassandra on ubuntu 16.04.

I successfully finished all the steps till this one

```
udo apt-get install cassandra
```

this step giving me error as below:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
cassandra is already the newest version (3.11.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up oracle-java8-installer (8u151-1~webupd8~0) ...
Using wget settings from /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer/wgetrc
Downloading Oracle Java 8...
--2018-01-17 12:33:48--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u151-b12/e758a0de34e24606bca991d704f6dcbf/jdk-8u151-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 23.198.126.121
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|23.198.126.121|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u151-b12/e758a0de34e24606bca991d704f6dcbf/jdk-8u151-linux-x64.tar.gz [following]
--2018-01-17 12:33:48--  https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u151-b12/e758a0de34e24606bca991d704f6dcbf/jdk-8u151-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)... 104.122.102.128, 2600:140f:4:1a0::2d3e, 2600:140f:4:196::2d3e
Connecting to edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)|104.122.102.128|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u151-b12/e758a0de34e24606bca991d704f6dcbf/jdk-8u151-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1516192549_30e1e90727719cbe83767ebf9151aff5 [following]
--2018-01-17 12:33:49--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u151-b12/e758a0de34e24606bca991d704f6dcbf/jdk-8u151-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1516192549_30e1e90727719cbe83767ebf9151aff5
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|23.198.126.121|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2018-01-17 12:33:51 ERROR 404: Not Found.

download failed
Oracle JDK 8 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cassandra:
 cassandra depends on openjdk-8-jre-headless | java8-runtime; however:
  Package openjdk-8-jre-headless is not installed.
  Package oracle-java8-installer which provides openjdk-8-jre-headless is not configured yet.
  Package java8-runtime is not installed.
  Package oracle-java8-installer which provides java8-runtime is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cassandra (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java8-installer
 cassandra
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

It says Oracle jdk is not installed. But I already have Oracle jdk8 installed in my system. Check below:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_161"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.161-b12, mixed mode)
$ which java
/usr/bin/java
$ which javac
/usr/bin/javac
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_161
$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
[sudo] password for hduser:
There is 1 choice for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_161/bin/java   0         auto mode
* 1            /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_161/bin/java   0         manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Something has changed about the Oracle download process, and nearly every install script on the Internet isn't working. Sit back and relax, this issue started early yesterday morning.

Comment: Hi @DoctorPangloss, thanks for comment, I think you are right ... there is some issue currently with the Oracle download process ... I tried `sudo apt-get upgrade` command it went well but at last i got same java error `Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java8-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can add Oracles PPA and install from there using apt-get. Follow the commands below.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer

javac -version
```

Comment: Hi @apesa, thanks for comment ...but `sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-insaller` gives exactly same error which I mentioned in my question above.

Comment: I realize that. Although I just set up 5 Linux machines for a DSE Cluster last week and used that PPA and it worked fine. Its got to be a webupd8team issue.

Answer (score 0):

This erorr looks like a ppa:webupd8team/java repository problem.  The download links are changed now and it's failing to download the JDK.