# "Could not find or load main class java.se.ee" while running sdkmanager --licences

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

When building my project on android studio, it asks me to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.

When I run "./sdkmanager --licenses", I have the "Could not find or load main class java.se.ee" error.

I found a lot of similar issues on stackoverflow, but non of the solutions provided worked for me.

I already tried:
1- downgrade to java 8

2- export JAVA_OPTS='-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-modules java.se.ee'

3- change sdkmanager file by adding : DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS='"-Dcom.android.sdklib.toolsdir=$APP_HOME" -XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-modules java.se.ee'

Comment: Hi have you fixed this issue?

Comment: This issue still coming... have u fixed it ?

Answer (score 53):

I had the same issue.
And solved by following the below steps:

1) Install java 8

2) Run command in terminal

> unset JAVA_OPTS

3) Then run command in terminal

> ./sdkmanager --licenses

Comment: Running the second point which is unset JAVA_OPTS did the trick. Thanks.

Comment: how to unset JAVA_OPTS

Comment: This worked nicely. The key was ./sdkmanager --licenses
thanks!

Comment: On Windows I ran this in the command line to unset JAVA_OPTS
set JAVA_OPTS=

Answer (score 19):

Well, it's been 4 months since you asked the question. You must have found the answer, but here is a way easy solution for others who are still looking for it:

```
JAVA_OPTS='-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions'
```

And, Voila the issue is solved!

**Why this solved the problem?**

Well I don't know the exact reason but, I also don't know why we tend to add java.se.ee through `"--add-modules java.se.ee"`, I tried removing it and error was gone! Maybe because **java11 removed EE module, and it was depreciated in java10.**

**It was just a blind shot which worked!**, If anyone knows the proper reason please comment it out!

Comment: I have upvoted you answer as it was helpful!
But can you explain why did this error occurred and what does your solution do? It would be really helpful.

Answer (score 8):

Unsetting `JAVA_OPTS` worked for me.

```
 1. unset JAVA_OPTS
 2. sdkmanager --list
 3. sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platforms;android-28"
```

Comment: unset is not recognised as internal or external command on my case

Comment: zsh: command not found: sdkmanager - Terminal can;t able to find this command

Answer (score 2):

Below steps helped me get past above Java error.

### JDK Version:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1111      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1111      manual mode
* 2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: <Choose Java 8>
```

**Procedure**:

1. unset JAVA_OPTS
2. In folder ~/Android/Sdk/tools/bin$ `sudo nano ./sdkmanager`
3. Change line# 31 to

> DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS='"-Dcom.android.sdklib.toolsdir=$APP_HOME"
>   -XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions'

4. Save the file and exit
5. ./sdkmanager --list

   Installed packages:=====================] 100% Computing updates...
     Path                 | Version | Description                    | Location
     -------              | ------- | -------                        | -------
     build-tools;29.0.2   | 29.0.2  | Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.2 | build-tools/29.0.2/

Answer (score 2):

After struggling to install platform tools from sdk manager with related errors

"Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module java.se.ee not found"

1. I first downgraded to Java 8 and then set Java 8 as default Java(JDK)
   [How to set or change default Java(JDK):](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21964709/how-to-set-or-change-the-default-java-jdk-version-on-os-x)
2. I tried installing platform tools again.

   sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platforms;android-28"

But then I got the error mentioned above. 
"Error: Could not find or load main class java.se.ee"

My search brought me here and

```
unset JAVA_OPTS
sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platforms;android-28"
```

This was the most closely related problem with a solution I could find and it helped me install platform-tools.