# Could not find or load main class java.se.ee' while running sdkmanager on windows

Tags: java, android, sdk, android-sdk-tools

I'm Not using Android Studio, I'm trying to run sdkmanager.bat file under /sdk/tools/bin but getting below error -

```
Could not find or load main class java.se.ee'
```

[image]

I have tried solutions available on below question. But none worked.
["Could not find or load main class java.se.ee" while running sdkmanager --licences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54287619/could-not-find-or-load-main-class-java-se-ee-while-running-sdkmanager-licenc)

I don't know how can i unset JAVA_OPTS as its mentioned in answers of above question.

**My Environment variables -**

[image]
[image]

Comment: it will be great to get reason for downvote

Comment: have you tried from the command line running a `set JAVA_OPTS=` (equal to nothing) and trying again the `sdkmanager`?

Comment: or setting `JAVA_OPTS='-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-modules java.se.ee'`. try with `set` in your command line first before doing the environment variable just to be sure your on the right track

Comment: @AndreiSfat yes i was able to use set command but unset was not working then it run unset using Set JAVA_OPTS=''

Comment: I don't think there is a `unset` command in Windows. You can just set to something empty. But you could just set the JAVA_OPTS from the environment variables as a system variable or something. Will that not work?