# Flutter java.lang.module.FindException: Module java.se.ee not found

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

I encounter this error when trying to run default flutter app in android studio :

```
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone x86 arm in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module java.se.ee not found
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

The java version (java -version on cli) i have is :

```
java version "1.8.0_291"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_291-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.291-b10, mixed mode)
```

Os : mac os Big Sur 11.3.1

When doing `flutter doctor --android-licenses` it outputs me `impossible to load main class java.se.ee`

How to solve this please? i have already searching solutions on google without success.

Comment: Which flutter version are you using?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54287619/could-not-find-or-load-main-class-java-se-ee-while-running-sdkmanager-licenc

Comment: Hello flutter v2

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it by reinstalling the `Android SDK Command-line Tools`:

Go to the android studio settings, click two times on the checkbox of `Android SDK Command-line Tools` to reinstall it.

[image]