# Android Studio - Unable to accept the Android Licenses

Tags: flutter, android-studio, sdk, flutter-doctor, android-licenses

I'm having a problem accepting the Android Licenses. I've looked for well over a month for a solve and haven't found one yet. My username on my mac contains the word (Deleted) with a space before it and I'm wondering if that's causing any problems.

I run `$ flutter doctor` and get this result:
[image]

I run `$ flutter doctor --android-licenses`

And I get this error:

`Error: Could not find or load main class (Deleted).Library.Android.sdk.cmdline-tools.latest`

I have all the SDK tools installed and updated to the latest. What I have installed is pictured below:

[image]

I have Java 8 installed and running, as well. Not getting any errors with Java.

Could use another pair of eyes to see what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my flutter doctor -v output:
[image]

Comment: Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` inside your android sdk location like SDK->platform-> Platform version (ex. 33.0)

Answer (score 0):

First set android sdk path  by  `flutter config --android-sdk <path-to-your-android-sdk-path>`
and run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` again

Comment: I've done that. Same result. The path is correctly set

Comment: Please follow this link for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67719983/flutter-java-lang-module-findexception-module-java-se-ee-not-found/67720572#67720572  for  install that Android SDK Command-line Tools

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate your help. If you look at the picture above, I have the latest installed

Comment: Can you share the output of the command : flutter doctor -v

Comment: Absolutely! I just edited my original post and added the image

Comment: Threre is space in sdk root path can you try by remove that space ? Users/jhicks (Deleted)/ is it still there or deleted ?

Comment: I really appreciate your help. That's what I think the issue might be. I honestly am not sure how to go about doing that on macOS. (Changing the username) without it messing a lot of things up.

Comment: You have to check path first if there is space then it will not work. please try that

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issued.

I have solved it by unistall Android Studio from control panel and re-install it again.
So Android Studio can install the missing SDK packages.

I also found this article useful: https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows#android-setup