# Problem with the command ionic cordova build android

Tags: cordova, ubuntu, ionic-framework

I have a problem with  the command ionic cordova   build  android.When I try to launch this command I have this  error > cordova build android
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=/usr/lib/android-sdk (DEPRECATED)
Requirements check failed for JDK 8 ('1.8.*')! Detected version: 11.0.3
Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT / JAVA_HOME / PATH environment variables.
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

Comment: you will have to set environment variables for android home, try re-installing android studio.

Answer (score 1):

It is clearly saying you didn't set the `java and environment paths`. To set up the environment follow [**`Android environment setup`**](https://gist.github.com/Ram12393/44c101787c9267d6fbf7137078c5a6be) Link

Answer (score 0):

You need to set environment paths.

If your OS is ubuntu, try below.

```
sudo gedit ~/.bashrc
```

in gedit editor, add these lines

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/<installation location>/android-sdk-linux
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Don't forget to save.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have the same issue in WebStorm and found solution. The issue is due to WebStorm  was written in Java and use v11.0.3 inside. So, do the following: 1. Open Webstorm --> Help --> Find action --> Switch boot JDK --> Change path to your v.1.8. In my case it's: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231" 2. add "JDK_HOME" in environment variables in your OS and set it's value: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231" Restart your Webstorm. That's it!

This also might be helpful:
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under

Answer (score 0):

As others have said you need to update path variables, I want to add a few more parameters along these.

In the project, directory use this command to check Cordova compatibility.
`$ ionic cordova requirements`
This should show what you are missing.
Cordova needs Java JDK, Android SDK, Android target, Gradle.

1. First install Java JDK as instructed [here](https://thishosting.rocks/install-java-ubuntu/).
2. Then you need to install Android SDK. If not installed, you can install it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34627928/11780625).
3. You need to install Android Target, for this open SDK Manager in android studio and install android targets. Install a latest one as well as an old one.
4. Install gradle. Use [this link](https://gradle.org/install/) to install gradle.

Finally you need to sum up all these in path so command-line can recognise these.
Open .bashrc with `$ ~/.bashrc` and add these lines. (If you haven't done already).

```
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64" # change location
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH


export GRADLE_HOME=/opt/gradle/gradle-5.2.1 # change location
export PATH=${GRADLE_HOME}/bin:${PATH}


export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk # change location
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/latest/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Change locations based on your installation directory.

NB: Make sure to add this line `export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/latest/bin` as old version of android studio's command-line has been deprecated and this is the updated command-line tool.

After this, reload the bash with `$ sudo source ~/.bashrc`

Then again check the requirements with `ionic cordova requirements` and this should display:

```
> cordova requirements

Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: installed android-29,android-28,android-26,android-23
Gradle: installed /opt/gradle/gradle-5.2.1/bin/gradle
```

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck on this for a bit, I had JDK 8 (1.8) installed but it wasn't finding it - adding the second line

```
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

in my .bash_profile then running
source ~/.bash_profile
Saved the day - here's by full .bash_profile for reference

```
export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_251.jdk/Contents/Home"
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/dylan/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/Users/dylan/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_AVD_HOME=/Users/dylan/.android/avd
export PATH="${PATH}:/$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:/$ANDROID_HOME/tools:/$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin"
export ANDROID_HOME=~/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=~/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_AVD_HOME=~/.android/avd
```