# How to run the Android Emulator with Cordova?

Tags: android, android-studio, cordova, sdk, phonegap

**Prerequisite**

- Android SDK is well installed (directory : /Users/gamecube/Library/Android/sdk)

**How to reproduce :**

1. Run this command : `cordova build android`
2. Run this command to launch android emulator : `cordova emulate android --verbose`

**Expected result**

The emulator is launched.

**Obtained result**

```
Command finished with error code 0: /Users/gamecube/Desktop/geocars/platforms/android/gradlew cdvBuildDebug,-b,/Users/gamecube/Desktop/geocars/platforms/android/build.gradle
Built the following apk(s): 
    /Users/gamecube/Desktop/geocars/platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
No scripts found for hook "before_deploy".
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/gamecube/Library/Android/sdk (DEPRECATED)
Running command: adb devices
Command finished with error code 0: adb devices
Could not find either `android` or `avdmanager` on your $PATH! Are you sure the Android SDK is installed and available?
CordovaError: Could not find either `android` or `avdmanager` on your $PATH! Are you sure the Android SDK is installed and available?
    at /Users/gamecube/Desktop/geocars/platforms/android/cordova/lib/emulator.js:176:35
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

**My questions**

*Why Android Emulator does not work?*

and

*Why is there this error? :*

```
CordovaError: Could not find either `android` or `avdmanager` on your $PATH! Are you sure the Android SDK is installed and available?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved my problem.

**How did I do it?**

- I opened Android Studio, and went to the SDK Manager.

[image]

- I clicked on the SDK Tools tab, and in the list displayed, I checked: Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest)

[image]

- I then clicked on Apply (then OK on the pop-up) to download the package in question.
- I added the path of avdmanager to PATH in my .bash_profile
- I have run `source ~ / .bash_profile` to refresh
- And I launched my command: `cordova emulate android --verbose` successfully since the emulator has opened well.

Comment: `I added the path of avdmanager to PATH in my .bash_profile` - and how do I figure out its path??

Answer (score 5):

Without Android Studio, merely with [Android Command Line Tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line) from Android SDK. Be sure these Android Command Line Tools (such as `sdkmanager` or `avdmanager`) are in the PATH, otherwise run them using the full path (for Debian/Ubuntu see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34556884/how-to-install-android-sdk-on-ubuntu) to install Android SDK).

Install the emulador

```
sdkmanager --install "emulator"
```

Install the platforms, example for Android API 32 and 33 (Android 12 and 13 respectively):

```
sdkmanager --install "system-images;android-32;google_apis;x86_64"
sdkmanager --install "system-images;android-33;google_apis;x86_64"
```

Create the Android Virtual Device (AVD), example:

```
avdmanager create avd -n emulator32 -k "system-images;android-32;google_apis;x86_64"
```

Confirm that was installed

```
avdmanager list avd
```

Run

```
cordova emulate android --target=emulator32
```