# Developing with Cordova can I use Android Studio on Windows 10 and Ubuntu for Windows together?

Tags: android, android-studio, cordova, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Needing some assistance regarding my installation and understanding how the two are integrated - if at all...
I've installed Android Studio on Windows 10, Switched on WSL(Windows subsystem for Linux), installed Ubuntu for Windows and using command line installed all the good supporting stuff like Cordova, Gradle, SDKMANAGER etc. Wanting to know if I need to install Android Studio for Ubuntu rather than use the Windows version so I can have the best of both worlds.

Had heaps of issues getting my environment to this point due to targeting deprecated components and installation differences in locations and environment variables. But, learned a lot on the journey.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcfKJ.png)

When I look at $PATH for Ubuntu there are references for Windows locations. So I would assume some interactions take place but knowing Windows must not modify file permissions for Ubuntu(Linux) files or folders...

```
**Some entries in Ubuntu/Linux PATH variable...
/mnt/c/Program Files/WindowsApps/CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_2004.2020.424.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc:
/mnt/c/Program Files/Java/jdk-14.0.2/bin:
/mnt/c/Python38/Scripts/:
/mnt/c/Python38/:
/mnt/c/Windows/system32:
/mnt/c/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/atom/bin:
/mnt/c/Users/Admin/AppData/Roaming/npm:
/usr/lib/android-sdk/platform-tools:**
```

So I have installed Ubuntu Android-sdk at the following location...

```
**/usr/lib/android-sdk**
```

[THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34556884/how-to-install-android-sdk-on-ubuntu) link I found interesting - Android SDK can be installed in multiple locations - yeah that's helpful.

And Windows uses...

```
**C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk**
```

[Android Studio (Windows)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Sdqc.png)

The command line offers super powerful and fast results once you get your head around the process. And, Windows provides great GUI support and a more manageable interface. I'm hoping they are meant to run together and someone can explain because there's a lot or conflicting information out there.

I actually just noticed in Cordova Requirements for Android Target is now showing installed android-28 (was **Android target: not installed**) - I couldn't get this fixed previously but once I've finished this journey I will post items from my diary to assist others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you not to do that. Because Android SDK for linux is different than android SDK of windows. SO the andorid studio in windows will never properly work with the android sdk for linux. Also WSL linux should not be used for Stable android development because windows manages most of the components configured for Windows OS only.
If you really want to have more grip on the commands you want to type , my suggestion is to have a stable linux OS rather than windows.

Comment: Thanks @p-sekhar. I think I already knew the answer but after following the installation steps at the following link I became confused and pushed on looking for the fix as I went further down the rabbit hole - I couldn't go back.    [link](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html)

Comment: @ShawnUrquhart :)