# Running smartgit on ubuntu gives OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning

Tags: ubuntu, java-8, java, smartgit

I am new in Ubuntu. I installed the jdk using

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

following this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14788345/how-to-install-jdk-on-ubuntu-linux), then downloaded and ran smartgit but I have to face this error:

> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library
>   /home/admin1/.smartgit/7/jna-tmp/com/sun/jna/linux-x86/libjnidispatch.so
>   which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the
>   stack guard now. It's highly recommended that you fix the library with
>   'execstack -c ', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.

How can I resolve it? My system is 64-bit and Ubuntu 15.10.

Comment: Are there reasons for not using Oracle ?