# Where can I download Java JDK, as the Java I downloaded (twice) is JRK?

Tags: java

When I try to download Java, I download JRK. I want to download JDK, but I do not know where to download from. Can anyone help?

I am running Windows 10.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install the JDK on Ubuntu Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14788345/how-to-install-the-jdk-on-ubuntu-linux)

Comment: There's a few other questions that are similar about how to install JDK on different operating systems.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't really answer my question, because I am on Windows.

Comment: Why is anybody talking about Linux systems here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are on debian/ubutu and want OpenJDK, then this command should suffice -

```
sudo apt install openjdk-15-jdk
```

for CentOS and RHEL based Linux -

```
sudo yum install openjdk-15-jdk
```

for Arch Linux -

```
sudo pacman -S openjdk-15-jdk
```

If you are on windows or mac, its better to go ahead download Oracle JDK after accepting their terms & conditions from they site -

[Oracle JDK 15](https://www.oracle.com/in/java/technologies/javase-jdk15-downloads.html)

EDIT:
I don't have enough points to comment. May this answer increase my reputation such that I can comment, from next time

Comment: In a minute, I can accept this answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This shouldn't be a comment, in any case.

Comment: Note: if you are installing JDK for Android Studio, there are many incompatibilities with newer JDKs. For Android purposes its better to have an Oracle JDK 8

Answer (score 1):

You can download multiple versions of the JDK at: [Java SE downloads](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html) (version 15, version 11, and version 8 are currently available).